# Is it a possibility to run a sequence of commands forward and backward in pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reverse, forward

I'm learning JavaScript with the JSDares.com. There are several tasks, where a sequences of commands is duplicated in backward order. For example:

```
function visitCulDeSac(n){
  robot.turnRight();
  robot.drive(n);
  robot.turnLeft(); 
  robot.turnLeft();
  robot.drive(n);
  robot.turnRight();  
}
```

We can see that the first three commands are "mirrored" in the next three lines.

- The question: Is there any simple way to let Javascript to execute a sequence of code lines in reverse order to avoid the repetition?

I've tried to make an array from the sequence of commands, but JSDares doesn't let to create long strings.

Comment: You could create an array of function references and then loop over that array however you like to invoke those functions.  Whether or not that's *better* or *more clear* is a matter of opinion of course.  What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?  What "long strings" are you referring to?  I see no involvement of string values here.

Comment: Your question seems to be more about what the JSDares platform allows than JavaScript itself. Putting the properties in an array seems like the simple answer.

Comment: How are those property names "long strings"?

Comment: *JSDares doesn't let to create some long strings* - there shouldn't be any "long strings".   You may need to add each command to the array individually. Please include what you've attempted.

Comment: It seems, that we can't add more than 60 symbols in one row.

Comment: @TRos: If you're asking about limitations in JSDares, that sounds like a question for that particular product/vendor support.  It's not really clear what exactly you're asking about *JavaScript* in this case.  If you've made some attempt to write your code and something isn't working as expected *in JavaScript*, please update the question to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @David, I asked about the ability of JavaScript natively to execute some sequences of code strictly, like it is implemented for example in JQuery .reverse method.

Comment: @TRos: Yes, JavaScript can natively execute code.  Do you intend to have an array of function references?  For example: `[robot.turnRight, robot.drive, robot.turnLeft].forEach(function(f) { f(); });`  Is that specifically what you're trying to do?

Comment: @David, the JSDares doesn't support new syntax and seems to have a lot of limitations... I tried to convert the sequence of commands into the array through the shortened vars. I got smth like this: `var tR = "robot.turnRight();";
  var dr = "robot.drive(n)";
  var tL = "robot.turnLeft();";
  var actions = [tR,dr,tL];
  for (var i = 0; i < actions.length; i++){
    return actions[i];
  }`
But it doesn't work

Comment: I wouldn't be using JSDares, there are a couple of red flags: _jsdares is an open source proof-of-concept_ and _© Jan Paul Posma and University of Oxford, 2012_. It seems that this page may not have been updated in over 10 years! and therefore not keeping up with the rapid pace of development of the JavaScript language.

Comment: @TRos: Please update the question to include a [mcve] of your attempt and indicate what specifically isn't working as expected.  What "new syntax" are you referring to?  You're creating strings, not functions.  If your goal is to create strings and execute them as code, you may be looking for the `eval` function.  Though keep in mind `eval` can be dangerous to use (if/when using user input anywhere in the string) and a pain to debug.

Comment: @phuzi, seems you are right. There are a lot of things that doesn't work at all.

Comment: @David, thank you for your attempts to help. It seems that only strict commands works at JSDares.

Answer (score 0):

Put the commands in an array of functions, something like this. You can then loop through them to execute them, and change the array to if you want to do it in a different order using the array methods.

```js
function executeList(list) {
  list.forEach(command => command());
}

function visitCulDeSac(n){
  const commands = [
    () => robot.turnRight(),
    () => robot.drive(n),
    () => robot.turnLeft()
  ]
  executeList(commands);
  commands.reverse();
  executeList(commands);
}
```